# How do I print subscribed dictinary value in RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, rx-swift

I have an `Observable` that returns a `dictionary`:

```
func myFunc() -> Observable<[String : MyClass]> {
    return service.getDictionary()
}
```

How do I get ahold of the `keys` and `values`?

```
viewModel.myFunc().subscribe(onNext: {
    print("", $0 )
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

There's no property like `.key` or `.value`. Do I use `map` or `flatMap` or how does it work?

Comment: Are you aware that `Observable`s represent _sequences_ of things? So an `Observable<[String: MyClass]>` represents a sequence of dictionaries. Did you misunderstand it as a sequence of key value pairs?

Comment: Right, so .flatMap {Observable.from($0)} would get me the sequence of key value pairs. But then, how do I get the values from there? Like printing out all the keys and their associated values.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you'd want `flatMap { Obserable.from(Array($0)) }`. After that, you can just do what you did in the question. `subscribe` and `print`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RxSwift 5.0 Tested

```
    func myFunc() -> Observable<[String : String]> {
        let dict:[String:String] = ["key0": "value0", "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2","key3" : "value3"]
        return Observable.just(dict)
    }


    myFunc()
    .map { (dict) -> [(String,String)] in
            let keys = Array(dict.keys)
            var key_value_array = Array<(String,String)>()
            for key in keys {
                let key_value_tuple = (key,dict[key]!)
                key_value_array.append(key_value_tuple)
            }

        return key_value_array
    }.flatMap { Observable.from($0) }
        .subscribe(onNext: { (tuple) in
        print("Key is \(tuple.0)")
        print("Value is \(tuple.1)")
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Then log in console is

```
Key is key0
Value is value0
Key is key1
Value is value1
Key is key3
Value is value3
Key is key2
Value is value2
```